# Then() completing before Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I am having some basic issue here with JS Promises. Here's my full code

```
'use strict'
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');
var os = require('os');

const options = {
    uri: url,
    normalizeWhitespace: true,
    transform: function (body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
    }
};

let results = []
let results2 = []

rp(options)
.then(($) => {
    $('.col-xs-4 .grid-item').each(function (i, elem) {
        let temp = $(this).find(".prod-image").attr("style")
        let productImageUrl = temp.substring(temp.indexOf("background-image:url('") + 22, temp.indexOf("')"))
        let detailUrl = $(this).find(".prod-image").attr("href")
        let title = $(this).find(".title").text()
        let description = $(elem).children().eq(4).attr("content")

        results.push({
            "productImageUrl": productImageUrl,
            "detailUrl": detailUrl,
            "title": title,
            "description": description
        })
    });
})
.then(() => {
    results.forEach(item => {
        const options1 = {
            uri: item.detailUrl,
            normalizeWhitespace: true,
            transform: function (body) {
                return cheerio.load(body);
            }
        };

        rp(options1)
            .then(($) => {
                console.log(5)
                let temp = $('#prod-title').text()
                let unit = temp.substring(temp.indexOf('Size: ') + 6, temp.indexOf('mL') - 1)
                let retail = temp.substring(temp.indexOf('Retail: $') + 9, temp.indexOf(' A'))
                let wholesale = temp.substring(temp.indexOf('Wholesale: $') + 12, temp.indexOf(' A') + 21)
                results2.push({
                    "productImageUrl": item.productImageUrl,
                    "detailUrl": item.detailUrl,
                    "title": item.title,
                    "description": item.description,
                    "unit": unit,
                    "retail": retail,
                    "wholesale": wholesale
                })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    })
})
.finally(() => {
    console.log("FINALLY " + results2)
    let header = "Handle,Title,Body" + os.EOL

    fs.writeFile("./file.csv", header, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });

    for (let item of results2) {
        console.log(2)
        let hyphenateTitle = item.title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        let line = hyphenateTitle + "," + item.title + "," + item.description + "," + vendor + ',"","",true,Title,Default Title,,,,,SKU,10000,,1,deny,manual,' + item.retail + "," + item.wholesale + "," + 'true,true,"",' + item.productImageUrl + "," + ',1,,false,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,kg,' + os.EOL
        fs.appendFile("./file.csv", line, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            } else {
                // done
            }
        })
    }
})

.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The idea is that in the first `then()` I will read the HTML page and find some URLs. I will push that information to the `results` array.

Then, on the second `then` the idea is to iterate over each item in the array and go to the second page, extract more information and push it to `results`

`Finally`, get that whole information in a csv.

This is the output in the console:

```
FINALLY 
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
```

So as you can see the last `then` is running before the middle one (but after the top most one.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

**EDIT 1**
This is new code as suggested by one the commenters:

```
'use strict'
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');
var os = require('os');

const options = {
    uri: url,
    normalizeWhitespace: true,
    transform: function (body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
    }
};

let results = []
let results2 = []

rp(options)
    .then(($) => {
        console.log("FIRST THEN")
        $('.col-xs-4 .grid-item').each(function (i, elem) {
            let temp = $(this).find(".prod-image").attr("style")
            let productImageUrl = temp.substring(temp.indexOf("background-image:url('") + 22, temp.indexOf("')"))
            let detailUrl = $(this).find(".prod-image").attr("href")
            let title = $(this).find(".title").text()
            let description = $(elem).children().eq(4).attr("content")

            results.push({
                "productImageUrl": productImageUrl,
                "detailUrl": detailUrl,
                "title": title,
                "description": description
            })
        });
    })
    .then(($) => {
        console.log("SECOND THEN")
        return Promise.all(results.map( item => {
            console.log("SECOND THEN INNER")
            const options1 = {
                uri: item.detailUrl,
                normalizeWhitespace: true,
                transform: function (body) {
                    return cheerio.load(body);
                }
            };

            rp(options1)
                .then(($) => {
                    console.log("SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'")
                    let temp = $('#prod-title').text()
                    let unit = temp.substring(temp.indexOf('Size: ') + 6, temp.indexOf('mL') - 1)
                    let retail = temp.substring(temp.indexOf('Retail: $') + 9, temp.indexOf(' A'))
                    let wholesale = temp.substring(temp.indexOf('Wholesale: $') + 12, temp.indexOf(' A') + 21)
                    results2.push({
                        "productImageUrl": item.productImageUrl,
                        "detailUrl": item.detailUrl,
                        "title": item.title,
                        "description": item.description,
                        "unit": unit,
                        "retail": retail,
                        "wholesale": wholesale
                    })
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        }))
    })
    .finally(($) => {
        console.log("FINALLY " + results2)
        let header = "Handle,Title,Body" + os.EOL

        fs.writeFile("./file.csv", header, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        });

        for (let item of results2) {
            console.log(2)
            let hyphenateTitle = item.title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
            let line = hyphenateTitle + "," + item.title + "," + item.description + "," + vendor + ',"","",true,Title,Default Title,,,,,SKU,10000,,1,deny,manual,' + item.retail + "," + item.wholesale + "," + 'true,true,"",' + item.productImageUrl + "," + ',1,,false,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,kg,' + os.EOL
            fs.appendFile("./file.csv", line, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                } else {
                    // done
                }
            })
        }
    })

    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

And this is the output:

```
FIRST THEN
SECOND THEN
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
SECOND THEN INNER
FINALLY 
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
SECOND THEN INSIDE 'rp(options1)'
```

Comment: The last then is within the second one and not after it so it will be executed while (middle then) execution give the result like that you get

Answer (score 1):

In the 2nd `then` you are running an *async iteration*, nothing tells the wrapping Promise to wait the Promises inside the loop (in the `forEach`).

You should `return` the inner Promise chain to inform the parent Promise to wait, and since you need to wait for all the Promises in your iteration, you can use `Promise.all`.

```
.then( () => {
   return Promise.all(results.map( item => {
       //...
       return rp(options1).then(($) => {
            //..
        });
    }));
})
```

And you can either `catch` locally (on the inner Promise) or on the parent Promise based on your needs.

Please look at the [Promise documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for the details, see the section [common mistakes with Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Common_mistakes)

Comment: Hi @krampstudio. Thank you for your help here! I actually did try returning the promise in the second then() just like you mentioned, but that did not work. Something is essentially not working right with my Promises and the "promise-request" library in this line " rp(options1).then(($)", I think. I have changed the post with changes to the code you suggested, and the output. Please have a look